# 1 sample z test of proportions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, proportion, z-test

We are trying to work out whether what we currently do is accurate. We want to work out if a proportion (% scoring 5 on a 5 point scale) are significantly below a target score.

Normally a 1-sample z-test would use:

$sd = \sqrt {\frac{(P_t * (1 - P_t))}{n}}$

$z = \frac {(P_t - P_s)}{sd}$

where:

$P_s$ is the sample proportion, $P_t$ is the target proportion and $n$ is the sample size

Our understanding is that this z-value would indicate how likely our sample is to fall within a a certain distance from the hypothesised population. In our case though we're not testing against a hypothesised population but rather a fixed value. Based on this should we not calculate the standard deviation for our proportion using:

$sd = \sqrt {\frac{(P_s * (1 - P_s))}{n}}$

and then work out if $P_t$ falls outside of the spread of the sample proportion?

Comment: Simple calculation will tell you if the observed value is less than a fixed value.  Your null hypothesis assumes the population mean has a certain value (5) and then your analysis yields the probability of seeing a result as extreme as in the data based on chance, assuming the null is true.  Or perhaps you have a deeper question.  If so, in what way do you see a "hypothesised population" as different from a "fixed value"?

Comment: Sorry, not explaining myself very well. It's more a question around why the sample base size $n$ is used, but $P_t$ is used instead of $P_s$ - the standard deviation calculated is then the deviation of the target surely? but we're assuming that has no spread whereas our sample has an error based on not asking everyone within the population.


Think I may have just got my head around this - we might expect $P_s$ to fall somewhere within a region around $P_t$. This region varies in size dependent upon base size $n$. Is the actual location of $P_s$ inside or outside of that region